# size of a C pointer depends on?

Tags: c, computer-science

What does the size of a C pointer depend on?  Is it the width of the data bus, the width of the address bus, or the word size of the CPU?

I believe it should depend on width of the address bus since a pointer has to address that many locations. Am I right?

(I am looking for a reason for dependency , if any)

Comment: It could depend on the type it points to quite legitimately so long as it obeys all the rules.

Comment: The address bus and data bus are more or less unrelated to the native word size and native address size; the 8085 had 16+something bits addressing (+segmentation) on a 8 bit (character addressable) databus. The first 386es had 16 bit wide data buses. The 32 bit pentium has a 36 bit external address bus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the CPU architecture in question.  You can write portable code that takes this into consideration by using `intptr_t` (C99 only).

Comment: So the pointer size does not have a solid dependency on data/address-bus width, or word size . It is just an architectural decision ?

Comment: @LunarMushrooms - compiler design decision, yes.

Answer (score 10):

The size of a pointer depends on your compiler implementation.  In practice it's almost always the native word size of the architecture you're building for.

Notably, the C language standard allows that pointers to different types might have different sizes, the better to support Harvard architectures that have differing sizes of program and data memory, among other things.

Comment: "_Almost_" being the catch, since `int` is the _fastest integer_ and not the _widest_.

Comment: Who says `int` has to be fastest?  There are lots of 8-bit architectures for which the compiler uses 16-bit `int` by default.

Comment: Those same 8-bit architectures are some of the exceptions I mean - their native operations work only on 8-bit values, but they can address 16-bits worth (or more) memory, so their pointers are commensurately larger.

Answer (score 2):

Sort of a circular definition, but it depends on the size of the address space that the implementation uses to identify where objects are located. This in turn might depend on hardware, OS, or the whim of the C implementer.

So, if the implementation wants there to be 65535 potential places to store a `char`, then it will use (at least) 16 bit pointers for `char*`. For 4 billion or so (or perhaps half that, some implementations don't or can't use the top bit of pointers), 32 bit. For way more than you have RAM, 64 bit.

In practice, the decision is usually constrained by the OS that the implementation expects the program to run on. If the OS's memory allocation functions return a 64 bit address, then it's rather inconvenient for the implementation to use a smaller pointer size, although there might be hacks that work in particular cases.

If the implementation is going to run without an OS, then it will use a size suitable to the size of the memory map for the hardware it runs on. And if it runs with an OS, then the OS *probably* but not *necessarily* uses a size suitable for the hardware. I say not necessarily, because modern 64 bit OSes have a habit of supporting 32 bit processes, and so a program compiled for that 32 bit environment, running on the 64 bit machine, will use 32 bit pointers. The pointer size suitable for the hardware may or may not be the same as the word size on the same hardware -- often it is.

Finally, since some types are bigger than 1 byte, there could in principle be something to gain from using smaller pointers for larger types, and the standard permits this. Imagine a machine with 8 bit bytes, 16 bit ints, and 128k of addressable memory, on which `int` objects have 2-byte alignment. Then a `char*` needs to be at least 17 bits (which will occupy 3 bytes of storage), whereas in principle an `int*` would only need to be 16 bits (2 bytes of storage), because the least significant bit of the address of any int is always 0, and so does not strictly need to be stored. If the implementation could arrange to always use the addresses correctly, then it's allowed to make `sizeof(int*) < sizeof(char*)`. In practice, approximately nobody ever does this.

Answer (score 1):

The size of a pointer depends on what CPU architecture the program was compiled for.

Answer (score -2):

All pointers occupy the same amount of space in memory while the size in memory of a pointer depends on the CPU architecture that the code was compiled for.

Comment: Neat! So I can compile my code for _16 bits_ and have it turn 64 bits for a 64 bit platform?

Comment: @K-ballo: I updated my answer to clarify that your sarcastic comment is not true :P

Comment: Thanks, but actually the size does not depend on where the code is going to run but on the compiler used to build it (with the target platform being the main thing). Also, pointers to different object types can have different sizes within a single platform.

Comment: I was actually thinking the same thing as you have stated, just that I had trouble in phrasing it properly.

Comment: @K-ballo What do you mean by an object with reference to C ? Could you give an example where pointers are of different sizes

Comment: @AshRj: As I already said, that depends on the compiler used. For a given compiler `sizeof(int*)` may be different than `sizeof(char*)` or than `sizeof(struct UDT*)`;